# Issue with LEAD Technologies JPG V1.01 - Bad Image

Tags: image, jpeg

I have a few JPG images that seem to be corrupt - yet the program dealing with them has no problems at all. I need to convert them to a new database - using C# or Delphi to do it.
The images are stored in a DB (which I can then save to file if I need to) - and the image has the following starting text in the header....
[Bad Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnUpN.jpg)

When it should be something like
[Example of Good JPG Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f043e.jpg)

Note that the image has the text LEAD Technologies V1.01.  I have contacted the company and they are currently on version 20.x - so it is so old even their latest tools will not read this image properly.

Has anyone out there had to deal with this issue in the past?  If so - any thoughts as to how to deal with this one?

It looks as if the image is corrupted - but as I noted the original program can still use it as a image file...

As requested - Full Image to review
[Full Image Download](http://www.timeacct.com/files/BadFile6.zip)

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. You have some images. An unnamed program can read them. They need to be a database? No, now they are a database, but they could be a file. And suddenly every byte has now become the original byte plus an extraneous null byte. Please try to explain clearly.

Comment: Hello Mark,  The images are stored in a database.  A program (customer EMR application) uses them as a background image for some custom data entry process.  (ie they have data entry fields placed over the background image - so a user can enter the data on a form they are familiar with).  When I look in the database - the images are there with (as you noted) extra bytes.  I have never encountered this type of image file before (which makes me wonder if they are being deliberately corrupted by the vendor?).

Comment: I can export the images from the DB (I have tools to do this) - and when I do - the images are not viewable by any tool I have.       Does that help clarify the issue?

Comment: Can you share an exported image, for me to analyse?

Comment: Sure - how do I send it to you?   You can reach me via the contact information on my website (www_DOT_timeacct_DOT_com)  email will reach me directly...

Comment: You haven't really provided much to go by.. Why not just export one of the images and attach to the question (link, don't embed)? While obfuscated, there seems to be a JFIF hidden in there, somewhere...

Comment: Hello haralK - I have edited the post and added a file (inside the Zip file) to be downloaded so you can take a closer look at it.   Let me know if you have any questions.  This one is driving me a little bit crazy.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to analyse your files and see if I can work out how they are corrupted.

Normally, JPEG files have well-known markers in them, which consist of two bytes - namely `0xFF` followed by a second byte that is not `0x00`.

If you scan a normal JPEG file for markers, like this:

```
xxd -c16 -g1 -u normal.jpg | ggrep --color=always  "FF [1-9A-F][1-9A-F]"
```

you will get something like this:

[image]

and you can see:

- SOI (start of image) - 0xFFD8
- DQT (define quantization table) - 0xFFDB
- DHT (define Huffman table) - 0xFFC4
- SOS (start of scan) - 0xFFDA
- EOI (end of image) - 0xFFD9

If, on the other hand, you scan your images, you just get pages of junk - sadly I cannot work out what the pattern is. If anyone else can, I can probably remove it - so ping me with a comment if you can!

[image]

Comment: Hello Mark,  Thank you so very much for taking a look at these.  I am now talking with the software vendor and trying to get their assistance as well.   This was something that was written years ago (15+) - and I am now wondering if it is a Unicode vs Ansi string issue (they would have used strings to load/save to the database column?)   I will keep you updated.